# Do BroadcastReceiver, Service, and Activity share Application object?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-broadcast, android-context

I have among others the following components:

- a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in Manifest
- a STICKY Service normally started by boot complete which processes `Intent`s from the above `BroadcastReceiver`
- an `Activity` which binds to the `Service` (starting it if for some
  reason does not exist)

Under which circumstances do these components share the same Application object?

How come sometimes the `Activity` can bind to the `Service` while at other times `onBind()` of the `Service` is not called and the `Activity` receives a `null` `IBinder` in `onSuccess()`???

There are too many parts involved to share code now. Based on discussion I can share relevant parts when we got specific ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **YES**, `Activity`, `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver` objects do indeed share the same `Application` object

- *as long as the process in which they are run remains alive*.
- *and if these components are run within the **same process**, which is the default behavior*.

Occasionally, a process running your `Service` objects may be killed and a new one spawned later on. In this case, memory is reclaimed by the kernel (and not by the Dalvik VM) so that the `Application` object referenced is not the same as before.

Comment: This fits my understanding. I don't expect the application object to survive a process killing/restart. I expect that such a killing would affect all components of my app, right?
The question is whether it is guaranteed that for a recreation all components the share the same new Application object. The service can be recreated by OS since it was STICKY, or explicitly by Activity's or BroadcastReceivers startService.

Comment: when the app is recreated, all components would absolutely share the same `Application` object, no doubt ... except in the case that a `Service` is run in a different process. As you no doubt know, this can be done :)

Answer (score 0):

There is always some information that is needed in many places in Android app. It can be a session token for example.

A pattern that is sometimes suggested is to dump your data in the Application object with the idea that it will be available across all activities and other components such as Service or BroadcastReceiver.

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

    String name;

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And an App component can use it like below:

```
class NameActivity extends Activity {

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        // Just assume that in the real app we would really ask it!
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        app.setName("set name here");   

    }

}
```

So, yes, app components such as Activity, Service etc.share the same Application object as long as the process in which they are run remains alive.

Secondly, `How come sometimes the Activity can bind to the Service while at other times onBind() of the Service is not called and the Activity receives a null`

There can be different reasons why above may  happen:
1. Service which has `IBinder` implementation may have been killed by OS
2. Service is created and it may takes a bit of time for it to initialize fully. Before this initialization completes, if component such as Activity tries to bind to it.

Comment: I observe situations were on repeat retries to bind the result keeps null for at least several seconds. Did not test longer yet.